# I'm working on filtering a table using multiple attributes passed as POST variables during a form submit

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to use multiple ANDs in WHERE clause but unable to execute the query. The filtering is as:

1. `Select * from startstopdata WHERE date(start_work) BETWEEN '".$date1."' and '".$date2."'` 
   **The date in MySQL is DATETIME type and I want to apply search only on date**
2. `Select * from startstopdata WHERE name='".$name."`
3. `Select * from startstopdata WHERE start_mac!=stop_mac`
4. `Select * from startstopdata WHERE start_location!=stop_location`

I want to combine all these queries using AND but somehow I'm unable to fetch the desired result.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

if I understand right , you just have to make your query like this

```
Select * from startstopdata WHERE (date(start_work) BETWEEN '".$date1."' and '".$date2."') and name='".$name."' and start_mac!=stop_mac and start_location!=stop_location
```

EDIT:

try this:

```
Select * from startstopdata WHERE (date(start_work) BETWEEN '".$date1."' and '".$date2."') and name='".$name."'
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't executes when I form a query like this.

Comment: so i think you get a problem with your data in the POST , the first query works when you execute this alone ?

Comment: Yes, the queries work fine when I execute them individually. But not, when it comes to single query.

Comment: so maybe try to use an "array_merge" function of php,

Comment: I want to optimize my SQL query, not the PHP code. The PHP code is working all fine.

Comment: i really don't understand why my query doesn't work, are your sure that all your where statement are true when you used it ? maybe try to do like my edit

Comment: say me if you have some result just with this

Comment: so you have a problem with you data in the database or with your POST variable because this simple query should worked , are you sure you tried it on some right data where all statement are true ? because there is no problem with the query

Comment: I'll recheck and let you know ASAP.

Comment: It worked. There was a misplaced AND that was causing the error. Thanks  buddy anyways. :)

Comment: oh ok can you put the answer ? I look the query and don't see any mistake, so it's just for my knowledge, anyway it's good if it's work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from ".$database.".`startstopdata` where Emp_name='".$name."' AND (date(start_work) BETWEEN '".$fromDate."' AND '".$toDate."') AND (Location!= Stop_location AND MacAddress != Stop_mac);
```